# Magento 2 disable file preview in admin form

Tags: magento2, grid, file-upload, ui

I created grid form using UI component. In my UI form I use file uploader. How can I disable image preview? Because I upload pdf file and preview are showing blank square.
My form field

```
<field name="journal_pdf">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Journal</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Journal PDF File</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">journal_pdf</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendorname_modulename/journal/savejournal"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```